# Repeatedly calling a function that hits a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php file that echo's a json encoded word. I have a javascript function that retrieves this word. I want to call this function, check if the word returned is already in an array and if it is, I want to call for another word. I basically want to repeat this process until I get a word that isn't already in my array. I'm struggling with this so I need some advice on how to do this. I want to do this solely on the client side. Currently, when I call getWord() it returns undefined but the function itself works so I'm suspecting that the word just hasn't been retrieved at the time.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";

$result = $db->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$word = $row['word'];
echo json_encode($word);
?>


function getWord(){
        var word;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON("getWord.php",function(data){
                word = data;
                alert("1st alert: " + word);
            });

        });
        return word;
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#newRound").on("click",function(){
                    currentWord = getWord();
                    alert("SEcond alert: " + currentWord);
                    //check here if data is already in wordsSoFar arary and if it is, get another word from getword.php
                    document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
                    //currentWord = data; //set the current work
                    lives = 6; //reset lives
                    tracker = 0; 
                    incorrectLettersGuessed = "";
                    allGuessedLetters = "";
                    updateLetters();
                    document.getElementById('hangman').innerHTML = '<center><img src="stage1.png"></center>';
                    createTable(currentWord);
                    output.innerHTML = '<center>'+messages.validLetter + '</center>';
                    alert(currentWord);

            });
    });
```

Comment: Where's the source of `getWord.php`? Btw,`$.getJson()` is an [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) method. Your `getWord()`-function will therefore always return an empty value.

Comment: its just a database of words. Is there a way to do the code after calling the method only after getWord() is competed?

Comment: Does it alert the word? If it does, then please check the link about _asynchronous_ i posted in my first comment.

Comment: you dont need `$(document).ready` inside getWord function!  Futhermore - it breaks you logic at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the ajax call to your php server gets resolved after the rest of your program has finished running. At this moment the `getWord()` function works like this:

1. Create a variable `word`. At this moment `word` equals `undefined`.
2. START calling the php server asynchronously.
3. return `word`, which at this point still equals `undefined`.
4. After returning `word`, the async call will get resolved and the callback function will be executed.

Instead of returning a word from `getWord()`, you should return the promise this async call creates and handle the result in your main function. Like this:

```
function getWord(){
    return $.getJSON("getWord.php");
}


$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#newRound").on("click",function(){
                getWord().done(function(currentWord) {
                    alert("The current word is " + currentWord);
                    //check here if data is already in wordsSoFar arary and if it is, get another word from getword.php
                    document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
                    //currentWord = data; //set the current work
                    lives = 6; //reset lives
                    tracker = 0; 
                    incorrectLettersGuessed = "";
                    allGuessedLetters = "";
                    updateLetters();
                    document.getElementById('hangman').innerHTML = '<center><img src="stage1.png"></center>';
                    createTable(currentWord);
                    output.innerHTML = '<center>'+messages.validLetter + '</center>';
                    alert(currentWord);
                });


        });
});
```

In addition to this problem, It is unnecessary to use `$(document).ready` in the `getWord` function. The function will only be called when the document is loaded.

Comment: so if I put everything from getWord().done {...} in a while loop, i should be able to keep getting a word until my condition is met?

Comment: Performing async calls in a while loop will not work, because you can not wait for the result of an async call before continuing to the next itteration. The easiest way to achieve what you want to do is to send the `wordsSoFar` array to you php file so the server can return a word that is not contained within the array. This way you will only have to do one async call in javascript.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the php, you can use the solution provided by AlexandrX

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the problem is that in your `getWord`function `return` executes **BEFORE** the server answered and the `word` assignment happened. Try to use `$.ajax` with `async:false` parameter.